# null and default values in page template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Very often i write code like:

```
<img class="hasMenu" src="<%= (Model.Image==null)?Url.Content("~/Content/NoImage.jpg"):Model.Image.standard %>"
          alt="Main image" />
```

Is there any predefined function which could beauty this code? 
Something like: `ValueOrDefault(Model.Image.standard,Url.Content("~/Content/NoImage.jpg"))`

Answer (score 2):

If what you meant was:

```
(Model.Image.standard==null)?Url.Content("~/Content/NoImage.jpg"):Model.Image.standard
```

then you simplify that using the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
Model.Image.standard ?? Url.Content("~/Content/NoImage.jpg")
```

If you meant what you said, you could write a method like this:

```
static class Obj
{
    public static T OrDefault<T>(Func<T> func, T def)
    {
        T result;
        try
        {
            result = func();
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            result = def;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Obj.OrDefault(() => Model.Image.standard, Url.Content("~/Content/NoImage.jpg"))
```

Comment: But that doesn't work if `Model.Image` is null, then you will get the `NullReferenceException` anyway.

Comment: cool solution! one more advice: make this method like extention for Control.      "public static T OrDefault<T>(this Control c, Func<T> func, T def)"    and  use it without   "Obj."

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to check if a field is `null` and use its property in the same statement with basic operators part from the way you have already done it. There have been discussions about a "property null-coalescing operator", but I am unable to find it when searching the forum.

The way you coded it is the most efficient way and probably the way to go in terms of readability.